# Dateクラスから、日本時間を取得したい。

Tags: swift, ios

Dateクラスに日本時間を以下のコードのように設定しているのですが、

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.timeZone   = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tokyo")
dateFormatter.locale     = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-03-17 11:00:00")
print("test = " + date!.description)
```

print文の期待値は、"2020-03-17 11:00:00 +0900"
なのですが、実際には以下のようにGMTの時刻が出力されてしまいます。
"test = 2020-03-17 02:00:00 +0000"
日本時間を取得するには、どうすれば宜しいのでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-03-17 11:00:00")
print("test = " + date!.description)
```

を

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-03-17 11:00:00")
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
print("test = " + dateString)
```

とすることで、日本時間の文字列を取得出来ました。