# Swift 日付

Tags: swift

Swiftの日付表示を2020/04/12(日) みたいにするのと

時刻を20:24 みたいに表示するのはどうしたらいいですか ？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでの以前の質問で[Dateクラスから、日本時間を取得したい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/63949)や、[現在の時刻のみを取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/64033/)は参考になりませんでしょうか？

Comment: なりました ありがとうございます